# How to resolve Invalid character constant

Tags: xml, string

```
String xmldata ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
            + "<String type ='basic_registration_mobile'"
                    + " Terminal_Number ='10'"
                            + " Terminal_Name='PayQwik'>"
        <Machine_Id>ertiueoirtueo</Machine_Id>
        <Mobile_num>9980066466</Mobile_num>
        <Password>dklgfjkld</Password>
        <Email_Id>rututhipse@g.com</Email_Id>
        <Date>2014-09-25 11:34:45</Date>
        <Gender>M</Gender>
        <Photo></Photo>
        <Address>45456tgdfg</Address>
    </String>";
```

This String showing invalid charcter constant. how to resolve it

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Is this Java? Please add a language tag.

Comment: A very good argument for not trying to construct XML as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing string concatenate before `<Machine_Id>`. if it allow multiline string than place + operator and double inverted quotes before `<Machine_Id>`

```
String xmldata ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
        + "<String type ='basic_registration_mobile'"
                + " Terminal_Number ='10'"
                        + " Terminal_Name='PayQwik'>"
    + "<Machine_Id>ertiueoirtueo</Machine_Id>
    <Mobile_num>9980066466</Mobile_num>
    <Password>dklgfjkld</Password>
    <Email_Id>rututhipse@g.com</Email_Id>
    <Date>2014-09-25 11:34:45</Date>
    <Gender>M</Gender>
    <Photo></Photo>
    <Address>45456tgdfg</Address>
</String>";
```

**Edit:**

Replace this block

```
String xmldata ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
        + "<String type ='basic_registration_mobile'"
                + " Terminal_Number ='10'"
                        + " Terminal_Name='PayQwik'>"
```

with

```
String xmldata ="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
        + "<String type =\"basic_registration_mobile\""
                + " Terminal_Number =\"10\""
                        + " Terminal_Name=\"PayQwik\">"
```

Comment: Thanks your response but still it will getting same error.